# QtDataVisualization not available

Tags: qt

I have QT 5.9.1 which has the package QtDataVisualization. But when I use it in Qt Creator I get the following error:
error: QtDataVisualization: No such file or directory.

I have added "QT += datavisualization" in the .pro file.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Is it because I am using linux? Does QtDataVisualization work only in Windows?

Comment: How have you installed Qt? Have you used the online installer or have you used the ubuntu repository?

Comment: Has this problem been solved? I have a very similar problem with Qt 5.13.0 on ubuntu 16.04, installed with online installer. I specified "Qt Data Visualization" as an option, and many files with "datavisualization" in the name were installed. My project .pro file includes "QT += datavisualization".  Yet while qt creator designer offers "QtDataVisualization 1.3" as an import, the import fails with designer error message 'found not working import... "QtDataVisualization" is not installed'.  Extremely annoying. What am I missing?